# Delete Oldest Emails using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to delete the emails using MS Graph api.

```
string tenantId = "";
string clientId = "";
string clientSecret = "";
string sMailboxUserObjectId = "";

MessageCollectionResponse inboxMessages = null;
MG.Models.MailFolder mailFolder = null;
int? totalMessagesCount = 0;           

try
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new MG.GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    await graphClient
        .Users[sMailboxUserObjectId]
        .MailFolders["inbox"]
        .Messages["mail@domain.com"]
        .DeleteAsync();
```

But I need to delete only oldest 100 emails. Can you please help here... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a code to get top 100 user's messages ordered by `createdDateTime` property. Specify only `id` to be returned

```
var oldMessages = await graphClient
    .Users[sMailboxUserObjectId]
    .MailFolders["inbox"]
    .Messages
    .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string []{ "createdDateTime" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 100;
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "id","createdDateTime" };
    });
```

Iterate through the top 100 oldest messages and delete each message

```
foreach(var message in oldMessages)
{
    try
    {
        await graphClient
            .Users[sMailboxUserObjectId]
            .MailFolders["inbox"]
            .Messages[message.id]
            .DeleteAsync();
    }
    catch (ODataError er)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Above approach is working fine. Able to delete older n number of mails. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a single request (like the OP attempted to do) instead of N requests?

Comment: For deleting N messages, you can use [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching), but the limitation is that a batch can contain only 20 requests. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#batch-requests